# Button to copy selected items in multiple dropdowns to textbox

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to copy() the selections of multiple dropdowns into a textbox. Currently the code I have been working on below will copy only the first dropdown. I want each selection from all four dropdowns to copy over into one line in the textbox and be able to add multiple variations creating a list. Any suggestions?

Additionally I want to try taking it a step further and have the second and third dropdowns dynamically change based on previous dropdown selection. Ex. Selecting Building One in dropdown one will change dropdown two to only display Dept. one. This is a bit more work so if anyone could point me in the right direction on how to integrate these two functions is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for you help!

```js
        function copy() {
          var sel = document.getElementById("names");
          var text = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
          var out = document.getElementById("output");
          out.value += text + "\n";
        }
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
</head>

<body>
  </script>
  <select id="names" style="vertical-align: top;">
    <option value="Building One">Building One</option>
    <option value="Building Two">Building Two</option>
    <option value="Building Three">Building Three</option>
    <option value="Building Four">Building Four</option>
  </select>
  <select id="names" style="vertical-align: top;">
    <option value="Dept One">Dept One</option>
    <option value="Dept Two">Dept Two</option>
    <option value="Dept Three">Dept Three</option>
    <option value="Dept Four">Dept Four</option>
  </select>
  <select id="names" style="vertical-align: top;">
    <option value="Folder One">Folder One</option>
    <option value="Folder Two">Folder Two</option>
    <option value="Folder Three">Folder Three</option>
    <option value="Folder Four">Folder Four</option>
  </select>
  <select id="names" style="vertical-align: top;">
    <option value="Read Only">Read Only</option>
    <option value="Read Write">Read + Write</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" onclick="copy();" value="ADD" style="vertical-align: top;">
  <textarea id="output" rows="5" style="vertical-align: top;"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are using `id="names"` more than once on the same document. `id` is designed to be used to identify a single element on the page. You could use `class=""` to address multiple elements and then iterate through the collection.

Comment: @JasonAller beat me to the ID part. But yes, that is your first issue. The rest of your question is pretty vague, what have you tried yourself? Try researching `addEventListener()` to do something when the `<select>` changes.

Answer (score 2):

I've been experimenting with the AngularJS JavaScript library for the past couple of weeks and it makes accomplishing tasks like this pretty easy. Here's how you'd accomplish this using the AngularJS library:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-controller="textboxController">
  <select id="names" style="vertical-align: top;" ng-model="master.building">
    <option value="Building One" selected>Building One</option>
    <option value="Building Two">Building Two</option>
    <option value="Building Three">Building Three</option>
    <option value="Building Four">Building Four</option>
  </select>
  <select id="names" style="vertical-align: top;" ng-model="master.department">
    <option value="Dept One" selected>Dept One</option>
    <option value="Dept Two">Dept Two</option>
    <option value="Dept Three">Dept Three</option>
    <option value="Dept Four">Dept Four</option>
  </select>
  <select id="names" style="vertical-align: top;" ng-model="master.folder">
    <option value="Folder One" selected>Folder One</option>
    <option value="Folder Two">Folder Two</option>
    <option value="Folder Three">Folder Three</option>
    <option value="Folder Four">Folder Four</option>
  </select>
  <select id="names" style="vertical-align: top;" ng-model="master.read">
    <option value="Read Only" selected>Read Only</option>
    <option value="Read Write">Read + Write</option>
  </select>

  <input type="button" ng-click="copy();" value="ADD" style="vertical-align: top;">
  <br />
  <textarea id="output" rows="5" style="vertical-align: top;">
{{user.building}}
{{user.department}}
{{user.folder}}
{{user.read}}
  </textarea>
</div>

<script>
    function textboxController($scope){

        $scope.master={
            building: "Building One",
            department: "Dept One",
            folder: "Folder One",
            read: "Read Only"
            };

        $scope.copy = function(){
            $scope.user=angular.copy($scope.master);
        };

    }

</script>

</body>

</html>
```